# Ebib: edit completions

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to change `ebib--field-edit-functions` in Ebib to add `address` to its fields with completions. The manual says that you need to customize the user option `ebib--field-edit-functions`, but I can't find it. Nor can I do it manually in the init file. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: No, that's different. See [manual](https://joostkremers.github.io/ebib/ebib-manual.html#editing-field-values). I believe there's a typo there, by the way: `ebib-utils.el` only has `ebib--field-edit-functions`, as opposed to `ebib-edit-fields-functions`.

Comment: This question was [double-posted to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76710113/1319821).